Plotly not exporting images in Flask route with Kaleido
I have a Flask app where I need to display some images. Beside that I also want to store them locally with pio.write_image as explained in docs. This works ok, if used in regular python, when I am testing in helperz.py -
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ic("name=main in strategies_helperz")
    print(plotly.__version__, kaleido.__version__)
    # create data
    data_original = generate_dummy_data(symbol="BTCUSDT", num_records=100)

    # transform to dataframe
    df = klines_to_dataframe(data_original)

    fig = plot_ohlc(df=df, exchange="mexc")

    user="ZEoJt367"
    src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    folder_path = os.path.join(src_path, "screenshots", user)
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        ic(f'{folder_path} not existing, should create one!')
        os.makedirs(folder_path)

    fileName = os.path.join(folder_path, current_time + str(".png"))    
    saveScreenshot(fig=fig, fileName=fileName, width=800, height=500)

..and this is saveScreenshot function:
def saveScreenshot(fig, fileName, width=800, height=500):
    ic(f"def saveScreenshot to ${fileName}")
    try:
        pio.write_image(fig=fig, file=fileName, width=width, height=height, engine="kaleido")
        ic(f"image saved to ${fileName} !")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        ic(f"Error saving image: {e}")

...but if use this within the route in app.py file, which is one level higher in file hierarchy, it just hangs:
@app.route('/api/klines_for_plotly/<string:exchange>/<string:symbol>/<string:timeframe>', methods=['POST'])
def apiKlinesForPlotly(exchange, symbol, timeframe):
ic(f"def apiKlinesForPlotly - POST - for ${exchange}, symbol: ${symbol}, timeframe: ${timeframe}")
  
    klines_with_names=[]

    if exchange == "mexc":
        klines_mexc=getKlinesDataMexc(symbol=symbol, interval=timeframe)
        for data in klines_mexc:
            kline = Mexc_KLine(data)
            klines_with_names.append(kline)

    elif exchange == "binance":
        klines_binance=getKlinesDataBinance(symbol=symbol, interval=timeframe)
        for data in klines_binance:
            kline = Binance_KLine(data)
            klines_with_names.append(kline)

    # transforming klines_with_names to pandas df
    df=klinesWithNamesToDf(klines_with_names=klines_with_names)
   
    # creating a plotly fig based on df
    fig = plot_ohlc(df=df, exchange=exchange)

    user="ZEoJt367"
    src_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    folder_path = os.path.join(src_path, "screenshots", user)
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        ic(f'{folder_path} not existing, should create one!')
        os.makedirs(folder_path)

    fileName = os.path.join(folder_path, current_time + str(".png"))
    fig = plot_ohlc(df=df, exchange=exchange)
    saveScreenshot(fig=fig, fileName=fileName, width=800, height=500)
    fig_json = fig.to_json()

    return fig_json

In this scenario saveScreenshot never finishes.
I did install previous version of kaleido, as many with similar issues suggested, but still no luck. Could it be, that for use in flask route, the function should be async?

ok, I found the answer - pio.write_image is a blocking call that requires a GUI environment to run, and Flask is a web framework that runs in a non-GUI environment.
When you call pio.write_image from within a Flask route, it's trying to use kaleido to render the plot, but it can't because it's running in a non-GUI environment. This is why you're seeing the error message. BAsically, I should find another way to store images from flask route. There was an option with using Virtual Display, but I think I will just use maplotlib.pyplot for my need here.
